# WP_Query offset not working

Tags: wordpress

I created a new WP_Query for a custom post type, and I'm trying to dynamically alter the offset. My query is modeled after [Making Custom Queries using Offset and Pagination](http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination), but I changed it so it isn't using hooks since I'm not changing the main query. Anyway, the posts are displaying in the right order, and when I `echo var_dump ($new_query->get ('offset') );`, the correct offset is set; however, when I load the page there is no offset. Can anyone help me figure out why the offset isn't being applied?

```
function new_query_function ($next_topic) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        'meta_key' => 'topic',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );
    $new_query = new WP_Query ($args);

    $offset = ($new_query->found_posts) - $next_topic;
    $ppp = (int) get_option ('posts_per_page');

    if ($new_query->is_paged) {
        $page_offset = $offset + ( ($new_query->query_vars['paged'] - 1) * $ppp );
        $new_query->set ('offset', $page_offset);
    } else {
        $new_query->set ('offset', $offset);
    }

    $new_query->found_posts = $next_topic;
    return $new_query;
}
```

Edit: It may also be relevant how I'm implementing this function, so here it is:

```
$new_query = new_query_function($next_topic);

while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) {
    $new_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
    //etc.
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. For anyone who's curious:

```
function vici_apad_query($next_topic) {
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'vici_apad',
            'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                            'key' => 'topic',
                            'value' => $next_topic,
                            'compare' => '<=',
                    )
            ),
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC',
        );
    $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    return $new_query;

}
```

The implementation is the same, except `wp_reset_query()` is replaced with `wp_reset_postdata()`, since there is no need to reset the entire query.

I actually made my code simpler instead of most complex. What a surprise.